# Index of minimum element using J

Tags: j

In J it is trivial to find the minimum element of an array:

```
   <./ 5 6 4 9
4
```

But how to find the *index* of the minimum element using J?

(In case this is an XY problem, I should say that I want the index rather than the value so that I can look up the corresponding elements in other arrays.)

Comment: There are [special combinations](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations) for this task; look under "Sorting and Ordering": `x ({ /:) y`, `(i. >./) y `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I would use this

```
ind=: I. @: (= <./)
```

It starts with  the `<./` which returns your lowest value and it uses `=` as the other half of a monadic hook. Monadic hooks take the `y` argument and apply the rightmost verb to it and then the left verb uses that as its right argument with the original `y` as its left argument. So, `(= <./) 5 6 4 9` is the same as `5 6 4 9 = 4`   and this returns `0 0 1 0`. From there it is simple to use the monadic `I.` (indices) to return the index of the value `1` which is of course `2`.

This also will return multiple indices if there is more than one least value.

```
   ind 5 6 4 9 4
2 4
```

If you only want the first or the last value you can use the simpler monadic hooks that incorporate `i.` (index of) or `i:` (index of last):

```
   indfirst =: i. <./
   indfirst 5 6 4 9 4
2
   indlast =: i: <./
   indlast 5 6 4 9 4
4
```

Comment: Because it was mentioned in the XY problem part: If this is only used to index into another array with the same size and one wants all elements, the result of `= <./` can be used directly as index: `9 4 2 1 (#~ (= <./)) 5 6 4 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take the first element of the permutation that would sort the list: `{.@/:`. This has the advantage of working not only for list but for arbitrary arrays and gives you the index of the lexicographically least item.